# Finding limit by partial derivatives

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How can I find the limit

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (2,0)} \dfrac{f \left(2 + 4h , \dfrac{3h}{2} \right) - f(2,0)}{h}$

when $f_x (2,0) = 3$ and $f_y (2,0) = -3$?

I know the limit definition of partial derivatives but I could not combine these definitions to get the desired limit. Any hints would be very helpful.

Comment: Shouldn't the question have $\lim_{h\to  0}$ ?

Comment: This is the directional derivative. Note that using the partial derivatives you can form $\nabla f(2,0)$ and hence find the directional derivative in the direction $(4,3/2)$ as required.

Comment: @student that's correct.

Comment: @PeterForeman thanks for this nice advice